# Changing the effect of image after image is taken

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

***Functionality:***

User are able to alter the aging effect of the selfie image taken from a webcam. Therefore, user are able to change the effect of aging on the selfie picture that has been taken.

Therefore, the process flow will be this:

1. User take a selfie picture from the webcam
2. User will be able to change the effect of the image taken from original to aged(imagine a 90 year old wrinkled with aged spots person)

***What I have done:***

I have created the photo-taking functionality and saving the image on a canvas.

***Issue:***

I have never encountered a jQuery/javascript functionality that would allow me to change the aging effect of the photograph taken. There are some examples but they are all using static images as comparison. And at this point, I am directionless as to how to proceed.

Hence, I would like to ask for some help/assistance on how I should go about creating an aging jQuery function that would allow me to change the aged look of the photograph that has been taken from the webcam
thanks.

***Code:***

```js
var photobooth_selectedFrameIndex = 1;
var photobooth_snap_counter = 0;
var photobooth_isFirst = true;
var isPhotoboothType = true;

var photobooth_canvas;
var photobooth_context;
var photobooth_videoFeed;
var target_photbooth;
var target_photbooth_context;

function photobooth_snap() {

  target_photbooth = document.getElementById("target");
  target_photbooth_context = target_photbooth.getContext("2d", {
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true
  });

  $("#photobooth_snap_button").hide();
  $("#photobooth_camera_countdown").show();
  var photobooth_countdownInterval = setInterval(function() {

    //Take Photo Function

    if (photobooth_snap_counter == 0) {
      // Activate Flash from Backend Server
      ajax_flash("flash.do", "formType=flash");
      $("#photobooth_countdown_image").attr("src", "lib/img/photobooth/Ready.png");

      $("#photobooth_camera_countdown").show();
      $("#photobooth_countdown_image").show();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#photobooth_countdown_image").animate({
          width: "1000px"
        }, {
          queue: false,
          duration: 500
        });
        $("#photobooth_countdown_image").fadeOut({
          queue: false,
          duration: 500,
          complete: function() {
            $("#photobooth_countdown_image").css("width", "379px");
          }
        });
      }, 200);

      photobooth_snap_counter++;
    } else if (photobooth_snap_counter == 1) {
     
      $("#photobooth_countdown_image").attr("src", "lib/img/photobooth/3.png");

      $("#photobooth_countdown_image").show();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#photobooth_countdown_image").animate({
          width: "1000px"
        }, {
          queue: false,
          duration: 500
        });
        $("#photobooth_countdown_image").fadeOut({
          queue: false,
          duration: 500,
          complete: function() {
            $("#photobooth_countdown_image").css("width", "379px");
          }
        });
      }, 200);

      photobooth_snap_counter++;
    } else if (photobooth_snap_counter == 2) {
     
      $("#photobooth_countdown_image").attr("src", "lib/img/photobooth/2.png");

      $("#photobooth_countdown_image").show();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#photobooth_countdown_image").animate({
          width: "1000px"
        }, {
          queue: false,
          duration: 500
        });
        $("#photobooth_countdown_image").fadeOut({
          queue: false,
          duration: 500,
          complete: function() {
            $("#photobooth_countdown_image").css("width", "379px");
          }
        });
      }, 200);

      photobooth_snap_counter++;
    } else if (photobooth_snap_counter == 3) {
      $("#photobooth_countdown_image").attr("src", "lib/img/photobooth/Heineken_1.png");

      $("#photobooth_countdown_image").show();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#photobooth_countdown_image").animate({
          width: "1000px"
        }, {
          queue: false,
          duration: 500
        });
        $("#photobooth_countdown_image").fadeOut({
          queue: false,
          duration: 500,
          complete: function() {
            $("#photobooth_countdown_image").css("width", "379px");
          }
        });
      }, 200);

      photobooth_snap_counter++;
    } else if (photobooth_snap_counter == 4) {
      $("#photobooth_flash").show(function() {
        $("#photobooth_photo_stream").hide(function() {
          document.getElementById("photobooth_snap_sound").pause();
          document.getElementById("photobooth_snap_sound").currentTime = 0;
          document.getElementById("photobooth_snap_sound").play();

          $("#photobooth_camera_countdown").hide();

          photobooth_snap_counter = 0;
          clearInterval(photobooth_countdownInterval);

          photobooth_send();
          video.pause();

          $("#photobooth_photo_stream").show();
          $("#photobooth_flash").hide();

          $('#camera_option_page').fadeIn();

          stopIdleCounter = false;
        });
      });
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function photobooth_send() {
  // Send Capture Image to Backend Server
  var canvasServer = document.getElementById("target");
  var context = canvasServer.getContext("2d");
  var imageDataURL = canvasServer.toDataURL('image/png');

  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("POST", "image.do", false);
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/upload");
  ajax.send(imageDataURL);
}
```

```html
<div id="PhotoBooth" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=4; top:0px; left:0px; ">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1920px" id="photobooth_photo_stream">
    <tr>
      <td width="1920px">



        <video id="photobooth_video" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:0px; width: 1920px; height:1080px; z-index:5; transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: scale(1.0); -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);-moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);" autoplay></video>

        <canvas id="photobooth_canvas" style="display:none;" width="1890px" height="1080px"></canvas>
        <canvas id="target" width="1920px" height="1080px"></canvas>

        <div id="photobooth_camera_countdown" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:6; top:60px; left:-40px; width: 1920px; heigth: 1000px; margin:auto;">
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1920">
            <tr style="height: 1000">
              <td width="1920" align="center">
                <img id="photobooth_countdown_image" src="lib/img/photobooth/Ready.png">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div id="photobooth_snap_button">
          <img src="lib/img/photobooth/snap.png" class="Answer_button_animate" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:400px; left:570px; margin:auto;" onclick="photobooth_snap();" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1920px" id="photobooth_flash" style="display:none; background-color:#FFFFFF;">
    <tr style="height: 1080px;">
      <td width="1920px"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: show your code, otherwise ppl cannot help

Comment: What is the difference between the functionality with a static image and your image? I mean, once you created the canvas with the image you can get the "static image" from the canvas

Comment: @pablopunk in the demo that I have managed to find, they have 2 different static images that they are calling. And for now, I only have 1 single image which is the photograph taken. I don't really understand how will I be able to just add the effect based on a single image?

Comment: That sounds like quite a sophisticated effect, where is it coming from, is it code that you have, or an online service or third party component? Is the supplied code your own code or the example?  I notice it sends some data to the server, might the effect actually be done server-side? Understanding where that code is and what it expects to receive will help.

Comment: @Jon I have a few question to ask: 1.) Are you saying that the facial age manipulation effect is sophisticated? 2.) I am planning to either use an external plugin or create one from scratch by utilising webGL to  achieve the desired aging effect 3.)The current code, that is shown is my own code. It actually snaps the image from the webcam, and the image taken will be sent to the backend. 4.) However, at this point, I am interested in doing up the effect before sending it to the back-end server for storage and print. 5.) I just need some examples to lead me on

Comment: @Jon 6.) It is similar to having a doodling effect or sticker effect. But for this, I just need to be able to manipulate the image to show the different phases of aging.

Comment: @Luke 1) Yes, I would imagine creating a realistic effect of that kind would be a non-trivial task, so I was wondering if you are trying to use a plugin.
Can you provide a link to the example you are trying to use?

Comment: @Jon, the following plugin that I am trying to use is as follows:  `http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/`

Comment: @Luke On that page there is an example of a woman appearing both young and old but there is no indication of where those images came from. That plugin is just a way of presenting two existing images, while you are after an effect that will modify an image. I came across [this API](http://www.luxand.com/in20years/), but it's not free.

Comment: @Jon, yes!!exactly, the current plugin that I am studying is making use of 2 existing image, while I am really trying to achieve by modifying an image. Awesome, will check that out